# Search With LIKE inside a JSON object in Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to search in some fields that are stored as a JSON in a Mysql Database and have a problem with *cute* and *acute* symbols.

If I do a `LIKE` search in a text field, the behavior is that the two queries will return a match.

```
SELECT "match" AS name from table WHERE "cómo se hace" LIKE '%como%'

SELECT "match" AS name from table WHERE "como se hace" LIKE '%como%'
```

But if i do a search inside a JSON encoded field this behaviour is not consistent:

```
SELECT "match" AS name FROM table WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"es": "cómo name"}','$.es')) LIKE '%como%';
```

This query will not find matches with cute symbol in o (ó). The next one will find the match.

```
SELECT "match" AS name FROM table WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"es": "cómo name"}','$.es')) LIKE '%cómo%';
```

Why `LIKE` keyword is behaving this way in this case and how I can make it behave with the 'default' behavior?

Comment: Specify correct collation explicitly.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I found It when searching for it.